# missing WMI namespace on Vista/Server 2008

Tags: internet-explorer, namespaces, wmi

What is equivalent to the root\CIMV2\Applications\MicrosoftIE namespace on Vista/Server 2008?

The root\cimv2\Applications\MicrosoftIE namespace dates back to at least Internet Explorer 5.00.2920.0000, which happens to be the version of Internet Explorer that shipped with Windows 2000, but it looks like it is removed from Vista/Server 2008.

Comment: WMI interfaces are used far & wide in IT management scripts.
Scripting == Programming
WMI interfaces are used far & wide in IT management programming.

QED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no longer there, but a lot of the things it controlled have been moved into the registry, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I know that most of those settings are in the registry now. I've just wanted to know is there any new WMI namespace that covers the same settings as root\CIMV2\Applications\MicrosoftIE.

Comment: Ah, no as far as the research I've done this is gone since there are alternative ways to do everything that applies.  As far as compatibility goes, it's rather annoying.